# masking elements in an array using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to mask some elements in an array such that a mathematical operation is not applied to these elements.

I ran this code

```
import numpy as np

inp = np.random.randn(5, 5)
c = np.random.randn(5,5)
mask = inp > 0


inp[mask] += c

print(inp)
```

but I got this error

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (25,)
> (5,5) (25,)

Comment: See [numpy masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.html)

Comment: Have you checked the shape of `input[mask]` to see if it looks like you expect?

Comment: You can't add arrays of different shapes that are not broadcastable.

Comment: Also worth noting: Don't name variables the same as built-in functions, like `input` in your case would shadow the built-in [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function

Comment: `inp[mask] += c[mask]` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
inp += mask.astype(int) * c

# -- or simplified to:
inp += mask * c
```